# Non clustered index on too many columns needed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a stored procedure called `Search`with 14 optional input parameters. These input Parameters are to be searched against the table `dbo.Patients` in the database. The dbo.Patients table has exactly same 14 fields that are optional parameters in the `Search`  stored proecedure.

For each parameter value passed into the stored procedure, `Search` stored procedure calls a particular respective function to check if the values passed into the Stored Procedure matches with the value present in dbo.Patients table in the corresponding column.

So, what I mean to say is, I have conclusively 14 multiline table valued user defined functions and each function matches the parameter against a particular column of `dbo.Patients` table only.

**Question:**  For performance reasons, I do not think creating a clustered index on all the 14 columns is a good idea.

1. Shall I consider creating 14 non clustered indexes for each column or creating one index on all of them collectively is a better idea?
2. The second that I could think of is keeping all the index disabled and enabling them just before the relevant function is to be called ?

What could be the better way?
 As mentioned, I have 14 UDF's and all of them have select statement of the kind:

```
Insert into @MatchedData(RowNumber) select dbo.Patients.Rowid from dbo.Patients where dbo.Patients.firstname = @FirstNameFromUser;
```

I realize I should experiment this but just wanted to know if anyone has already done that or guide me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an index does not necessarily guarantee better performance. I think that creating non-clustered indexes on some of the fields may help provided they a large number of unique values but as always view your execution plan to validate the actual performance.